# ubereats menu API: quantity constraints for modifiers

Tags: uber-api

when trying to set the required quantity for mods with the min_permitted and max_permitted it's showing as a checkbox on the UE portal. while I am expecting to show as a plus/minus sign. how can I do that?

e.g. how i doing :
"quantity": {
"min_permitted": 3,
"max_permitted": 3
},

Answer (score 1):

I got this, you have to set the same configuration to the mod items as well what at the mod group level.
Ref:  https://developer.uber.com/docs/eats/api/v2/put-eats-stores-storeid-menus#request-body-parameters-quantityconstraint